# Compilation error with adding pallet_contracts to substrate runtime `environmental!(executing_contract: bool);`

Tags: substrate

After doing everything with certain documentation i am having issues while compiling pallet_contract.
I want to add pallet_contracts to the substrate runtime . Done everything in order but having this error.

1138: `environmental!(executing_contract: bool);`

while compiling and building. I am getting this error. Why ?? Any solve??